# When I update to Xcode15, I get lot of warnings: "Mixed ObjC ABI, xxx compiled without category class properties"

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode15

When I was using Xcode 14, I didn't encounter any warnings. However, after updating to Xcode 15, I suddenly started receiving over 200 warnings from third-party libraries. Does anyone know the reason for this or how to address these warnings without having to wait for the libraries to be updated? It appears that these warnings are related to the use of Objective-C in the libraries.

Warning like it:
`Mixed ObjC ABI, /Users/wanghong/Developer/alpaca/Pods/AppsFlyerFramework/iOS/AppsFlyerLib.framework/Versions/A/AppsFlyerLib[x86_64][26](AppsFlyerAES128Crypto.o) compiled with category class properties`

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

on Build Settings -> Link -> Other Link Flags, you can add -ld64 or -ld_classic

Comment: Keep in mind: Using -ld64 is a short-term workaround. "The classic linker can still be explicitly requested using -ld64, and will be removed in a future release." see https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/736590?answerId=764456022#764456022

Comment: How do I use these flags in Visual Studio on Windows that is paired to a Mac for Xamarin development? I'm getting the same errors and warnings as OP. I went into the Properties of my iOS project, then iOS Build, and entered the flag in "Additional mtouch arguments", but I get an error on build that the flag is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

For Xamarin.iOS projects, you can also use the classic linker, as suggested by [@david's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77256396/1356795):

1. Right-click on your iOS .csproj
2. Choose "Properties"
3. Under Build -> iOS -> Build, add `-gcc_flags "-Xlinker -ld_classic"` to the "Additional arguments:" field. Make sure you have done this for the correct Platform & Configuration.

Alternatively, you can add

```
<MtouchExtraArgs>-gcc_flags "-Xlinker -ld_classic"</MtouchExtraArgs>
```

to any desired `<PropertyGroup>` in your iOS .csproj.